# Deploying K2 blackpearl projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, k2

I am attempting to deploy a basic workflow from Visual Studio 2005 to a K2 blackpearl server. It seems that doing so directly is unsupported but regardless whether I try to deploy from client to server or use msbuild on a deploy package on the server I get the same error. The accounts I am using have export privileges on the server.

> Error 1   Task Error: System.Exception: Forms Generation publishing has failed: Please ensure that if you are deploying this project that you are not attempting to do so on client. Deployment package needs to be created and run on the server in order to publish forms correctly. - System.Exception: Forms Generation publishing has failed: Please ensure that if you are deploying this project that you are not attempting to do so on client. Deployment package needs to be created and run on the server in order to publish forms correctly.
>      at SourceCode.DeploymentTasks.FormsGeneration.ClientEventDeploymentTask.HasPublishedWebsite()
>      at SourceCode.DeploymentTasks.FormsGeneration.ClientEventDeploymentTask.HasPublishedWebsite()
>      at SourceCode.DeploymentTasks.FormsGeneration.ClientEventDeploymentTask.Execute()
>       C:\Users\dev3\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\K2 sandbox\InformationRequest\obj\Debug\Deployment\InformationRequest.msbuild   68  6   InformationRequest

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue when using Forms Generation in K2.

I believe it stems from either

(a) not having Web Deployment Projects installed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx)

(b) something else* going wrong, so just try working backwards from Forms Generation by restarting VS, recreating the Activity that contains this client event, or even recreating the project.

- this "something else" going wrong has often driven people to avoid using Forms Generation. In fact, the value added by Forms Generation is little compared with the control cost.  I'd suggest using ASP.NET with a Default Client event.  You can essentially recreate Forms Generation with fewer than a couple hundred lines of code to auto-detect the Process Definition and render Data and XML fields based on type, although you do lose some of the conveniences of field selection.